# Using SRP lib in a React Native project

Tags: react-native, expo, cryptojs

I am attempting to use a javascript SRP library called `thinbus-srp` (https://github.com/simbo1905/thinbus-srp-npm) in an Expo (React Native) project. It's getting hung up on the `random-strings` library depending on the Node `crypto` library. Of course, just doing `npm i crypto` doesn't work, so I'm not sure what to do next. How do I tell a dependency to use a different dependency, i.e. `CryptoJS`?

Edit: I see there's a fork called `react-native-thinbus-srp` (https://github.com/eXhausted/react-native-thinbus-srp) that may have solved this problem, but how do I use it in my project since it's not on npm?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up cloning the SRP library I wanted, plopping it into my main directory, editing the code necessary and using it locally. No npm involved.